# Exclude post with specific title post_title from wp query

Tags: wordpress

How can i exclude an post with specific word in the title.

I need something like:

```
$args = array(
    's' => 'title' // i need something that will exclude this "!title"
```

with 's' i can search for post with that title but i need to exclude it not show it!

Or something like:

```
$wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE **NOT** '%Exclude this%'
```

**Like NOT** i need something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Well very easy just add - in front of the title that will exclude it

```
$args = array(
's' => '-title' // will exclude all post with the title name "title"
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work. it will search for a post with title -title